# Client doesn't call web.api json service

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I have a strange problem where a program using a simple external call to an web.api.
The program is working on about 50% of the clients I've tried it on.

The program uses a WebClient to fetch the data.

On my local machine where the program works, I have analyzed the call to the json service via fiddler and everything works fine, a request is made and json is returned.

When checking fiddler on a client where the program doesn't work, there is not even a request being done according to fiddler.

This makes me believe that there might be some policy on these computer that does not allow external calls.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

/Peter

Comment: Such a policy would prevent any HTTP call. Are you sure your program isn't silently ignoring exceptions? Does your program use a proxy? Fiddler acts as a system proxy. If your program ignores the system proxy, or if it uses its own, Fiddler won't see the requests